# exo player not found?

Tags: android, exoplayer

i did all things watching a tutorial but my app still crashes, here is the full code, i added the internet permission too, nothing worked i tried to change method calls position but still nothing worked, i tried many times but still had the same problem that it's null and i don't know how is that possible as i am invoking the id, what is it i am doing wrong.

main activity

```java
package com.example.section26_media_v2;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
   private PlayerView playerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, new DefaultTrackSelector());

        // to associate the exoPlayer with exoPlayerView
        playerView.setPlayer(player);


        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name)));


        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse("http://blueappsoftware.in/layout_design_android_blog.mp4"));

        player.prepare(videoSource);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        playerView.setPlayer(null);
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
}
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.section26_media_v2, PID: 5354
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.section26_media_v2/com.example.section26_media_v2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView.setPlayer(com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView.setPlayer(com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.section26_media_v2.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:50)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1333)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6992)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
```

Answer (score 1):

Null pointer try to say that your PlayerView is null. That can happen because the findviewbyid is not matching with the right one on your XML. Be sure your id matches your XML and the.Java java file

Comment: i thought of that too and checked it, but as you can see the id in main perfectly matches the one in XML file, and i also have only one id.

Comment: check setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) is correct layout or not ?????

Comment: it now works, the problem was i was using `public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);` instead of `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`